# Do the following equations for the conditional expectations hold under the given assumptions?

Tags: independence, conditional-expectation, marginal-distribution, sigma-algebra

Let $(\Omega,F,\mathbb{F}=(F_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}},P)$ be a filtered probability space and $(Z_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}$ be a sequence of integrable iid random variables. Denote $F_n=\sigma(Z_o,\dots,Z_n)\forall n\in\mathbb{N_0}$. Does is hold that:

1. $\mathbb{E}[\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}Z_kZ_{k-1}|F_s]=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{s}Z_kZ_{k-1} \forall s\leq n,$ if $\mathbb{E}[Z_0]=0$
2. $\mathbb{E}[\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}Z_k(Z_{k-1}-1)|F_s]=\sum \limits_{k=1}^{s}Z_k(Z_{k-1}-1) \forall s\leq n$, if $\mathbb{E}[Z_0]=0$
3. $\mathbb{E}[\prod \limits_{k=1}^{n}Z_k|F_s]=\prod \limits_{k=1}^{s}Z_k, \forall s\leq n$, if $\mathbb{E}[Z_0]\gt0$

   I believe that the first and the second equations hold, whereas the third equation is false, because $\forall k>s$ we know that $Z_k$ and $F_s=\sigma(Z_0,...,Z_s)$ are independent since $Z_0,...,Z_n$ are iid. Therefore, for the first equation, $\mathbb{E}[\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}Z_kZ_{k-1}|F_s]=\mathbb{E}[\sum \limits_{k=1}^{s}Z_kZ_{k-1}|F_s]+\mathbb{E}[\sum \limits_{k=s+1}^{n}Z_kZ_{k-1}|F_s] \overset{iid}{=} \mathbb{E}[\sum \limits_{k=1}^{s}Z_kZ_{k-1}|F_s]+\sum \limits_{k=s+1}^{n}Z_{k-1}\mathbb{E}[Z_k]|F_s]\overset{independent}{=}\mathbb{E}[\sum \limits_{k=1}^{s}Z_kZ_{k-1}|F_s]+\sum \limits_{k=s+1}^{n}Z_{k-1}\mathbb{E}[Z_k]=\mathbb{E}[\sum \limits_{k=1}^{s}Z_kZ_{k-1}|F_s]\overset{def \ of \ F_s}{=}\sum \limits_{k=1}^{s}Z_kZ_{k-1}$. 
   The second equation is similar.
   Can someone validate that ? I'm not quite sure how to work with conditional expectations, yet.

Comment: In addition to supposing $Z_n=Y_n,$ you must be making some strong assumptions about the expectations: perhaps $(Z_n)$ is supposed to be a martingale?

Comment: You are right, it is supposed to be $Z_n$ instead of $Y_n$. Furthermore, we know, that the following holds: 1. $\\ \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}Z_kZ_{k-1}$ is $F_n$ measurable ( as the sum of a product of $F_n$ measurable functions) and 2. $\mathbb{E}[ |\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n}Z_kZ_{k-1}|\lt \infty$, which can be shown quite easily. The question remains, if one of the equations (1, 2 or 3) from above hold, because if that is the case, then  the respective term describes a martingale